# Is there anyone who help me to build iOS linphone on Yosemite 10.10.2?

Tags: ios, xcode, linphone

I download the linphone SDK, installed MacPorts and then when writing following command in terminal, i got 'Xcode not installed properly....' and then I follow their rules to install left XCode's software, that are also done on my terminal screen.

```
sudo port install automake autoconf libtool pkgconfig intltool wget cunit \
        antlr3 speex readline sqlite3 openldap libupnp \
        ffmpeg-devel -gpl2
```

But here problem persists...

Please help me to get out from this problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there's few Steps of compiling the Linphone SDK.

- Install dependencies
- Install Antlr 3
- Install gas-preprosessor.pl
- Symlink libtoolize to glibtoolize
- Link host strings to simulator SDK
- Link /opt/local/bin to /usr/local/bin

Then Build

- git clone git://git.linphone.org/linphone-iphone.git --recursive
- Set the SDK version
- ./prepare.py && make(The link below use "make" instead which is deprecated)

Detailed steps as:[Building linphone SDK using Homebrew](http://www.successmonkey.co.nz/blog/building-linphone-for-ios)

Answer (score 0):

I currently have to do the same thing and you don't have to get through this steps.....been there done that...
Instead you can download instead this the SDK  by searching this on google  liblinphone-iphone-sdk-2.2.5.zip

And, of course check the latest news from Linphone, to be updated.

Best Approach would be to clone and start this: 
https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-iphone

And very important use a Xcode 6 version. Xcode 7 gives you some errors as they introduced some new features and depracated old stuff.
If you don't know how to use git, please pause what you are doing and dedicate some time to do it because will have to do it multiple time during your career. 
Hope this helps! Good luck